# Can you bundle SQLite in your exe file?

Tags: c#, wpf, database, sqlite

I am relatively new to programming and am making a tiny application that is basically a calculator for a particular game. As such I would like the user to be able to change some of the values related to the game and the changes to persist between application executions, i.e. to be saved but I don't want to use more than 1 file (the EXE).

I know about SQLite and ILMerge but am not sure if it is possible to make it so that the EXE file includes in itself a tiny database so that the user can alter and save values in that exe. I tried searching for that but don't know what exact terminology to use so I had no luck.

Comment: If you want a persistent DB, you'll always have at least one file outside your .exe. You can of course use always the same file, so all your data will end up in that db file. For deployment, you can either ship one empty db with all needed tables etc along with your .exe or create it from code if the file does not exist.

Comment: @Fildor, I was hoping there would be some way to package the DB file inside the EXE or something. :(

Comment: Another idea would be to store a "backup" file somewhere on a cloud space and have the app use an in-mem SQlite DB that is restored from that cloud file on startup.

Comment: *Inside* the .exe - no possibility that I am aware of. At least not for the data. The .dll s *may* be possible fiddling around with compiler / linker but I have never tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not as complex as you think

You can either use NuGet or download it yourself.

Using NuGet then search for "System.Data.SQLite", and install it.
This will add the references you need to your project.

And that is basically it!  When you build/compile then you will have everything you need included with your app in your output directory (which will include DLLs).  No need to embed any other .exe or anything else with your app (except your database of course!)

This article shows getting started with SQLite:  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22165/Using-SQLite-in-your-C-Application

In your case, I think your app is so simple that maybe you don't need a database and simple persistence to a data file (maybe in JSON format) is enough.  But you can still do this as a learning exercise.

Comment: I see, the NuGet is certainly very helpful but won't that create additional files (DLLs) that I will have to "ship" with my exe in order for this to work? I was looking for a way to have my desired functionality in only a single exe file.

Comment: Yes.  But you said you know ILMerge, which will allow you to merge all the DLLs into a single exe.

Comment: You can also embed your database file into the .exe as a "resource".  But you need to extract it when the application starts, in order to write your changes into it.

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified I have only _heard_ of "ILMerge". :D I suppose it can merge the DLL into the EXE and solve my problem?

Comment: This might help:  http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/ilmerge.aspx  and https://albao.wordpress.com/2012/02/24/merge-multiple-net-4-assemblies-into-one-using-ilmerge/